# Arduino Zero - Region Ram overflowed with stack

Tags: arduino

I have some code that uses nested Structs to store device parameters see below:

This is using an Ardunio Zero ( Atmel SAMD21)

The declares Storeage with up to 3 networks each network with 64 devices.

I would like to use 5 networks however when I increase the networks to 4 the code will not compile.

I get region RAM overflowed with stack / RAM overflowed by 4432 bytes.

I understand that this is taking more ram then I have? I am looking to see if there is a solution using a different method to achieve the same thing but get it to fit?

```
 struct device {
   int   stat;
   bool  changed;
   char  data[51];
   char  state[51];
   char  atime[14];
   char  btime[14];
   };

struct outputs {
   device fitting[64];
   };


struct storage {
    int deviceid =0;
    int addstore =0;
    bool set;
    bool run_events = false;
    char authkey[10];
    outputs network[3];
 } ;

storage data_store;
```

Comment: You're allocating more RAM than the linker thinks is available for your device. You need to use some external storage or find some other strategy.

Comment: Write 100 times on a whiteboard: "Arduino is not C nor exactly C++! I must not spam tags."

Answer (score 1):

Well, the usual approches are:

1. Consider if all or any of the data is actually read-only, and thus can be made `const` (which should move it to read-only memory, if that fails you can usually force it by adding compiler-specific magic).
2. Figure out means of representing the data using fewer bits. For instance using 14 bytes for each of three timestamps might seem excessive; switching these to 32-bit timestamps and generating the strings when needed would save around 70%.
3. If there are duplicates, then perhaps each `storage` doesn't need three unique `outputs`, but can instead store pointers into a shared "pool" of unique configurations.
4. If not all 64 `fitting`s are used, that array could also be refactored into having non-constant length.

It's hard to be more specific since I don't know your data or application well enough.

Comment: Thanks What do you suggest to make the length of fittings non-constant?

Comment: I have looked to change atime to a uint32_t. But the value is altered. uint32_t atime = 121522150517; when printed =  1263066229 - Why does it change?

Comment: @Jeremy Because `121522150517` does not fit in 32 bits. What resolution is that time? Normally you'd use seconds since 1970-01-01 and that doesn't overflow 32 bits for a while, yet.

Comment: Thanks.  I have now reduced the size of the struct by writing each network to sd card. So only one network is loaded at a time.  Time was in the format hh:mm:ss:dd:mm:yy

Answer (score 1):

Your struct is taking too much place. That's all. Assuming chars, ints and bools are internally 1 byte each, your `device` struct takes 132 bytes. Then, your `outputs` struct takes 8448 bytes or 8.25Kb.   Your unit has 32Kb of RAM...